# How do I keep all my objects in my Java game the same across all monitors and resolutions?

Tags: java, geometry, coordinates

I'm a beginner to java and I'm working on my first game :)

For my java game, do I need to position and size everything relative to my monitor settings? for instance

to position and size things, I use Point(x,y)

Shall I rather do "ScaledPoint" where "ScaledPoint"  is equal to

```
public Point ScaledPoint(int x,int y)
{  
 return new Point(x*ScreenWidth/1680,y*ScreenHeight/1050);
}
```

Since my ScreenWidth and ScreenHeight as I'm developing the game world is 1680*1050 px?

To keep everything the same across different resolutions? I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Does it matter? Write your code so you're not working against an absolute value if your can. If this is not possible, render everything at the "normal" scale to a backing buffer and scale the buffer when its rendered onto the screen

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a broad question, but a general principle would be to define your game space in some sort of device-independent coordinates with units small enough to accommodate your expected screen sizes and then some.

Then, scale those coordinates for each display depending on the display size. The scaling factor could possibly be something the user could configure.

The objective here is (as it is in many cases in computer science and software development) to separate the *content* from its *presentation*.  You work internally in coordinates that are meaningful to you and consistent, and leave the layout on the screen to the presentation layer.  This gives you the greatest flexibility and also simplifies the game engine programming since you're not worrying about display resolution at that level, only at the display level.

This principle (separation of concerns) is why we moved from HTML-only in the web's prehistoric era (the 1990s), where HTML dictated both content and layout, to today's HTML+CSS where the HTML specifies the content and CSS can be used to present the information differently for different browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm still a bit confused though. I'm new to all of this, much of it is still jargon but I can learn. So what is wrong with me doing this displayed above? Would this not keep everything consistent across all resolutions?

Comment: Maybe, but I can't tell from the code you provided.  The key is to have the game logic work in a consistent grid that has no direct connection to the display.  Scaling happens only in the code that is responsible for taking your game objects and putting them on the screen.